# Incompatibilidade entre onkeyup e máscara de data?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou com um problema utilizando `onkeyup` numa máscara de data que é o seguinte: quando tento utilizar o backspace para modificar a data, não consigo passar da barra (só se  mantenho o botão pressionado). A barra fica desaparecendo e aparecendo (faça o teste aqui no [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/xqxj02p2/), ou abaixo em "Executar trecho de código", digite uma data qualquer e depois tente apagar).

Isso só acontece se estou utilizando `onkeyup`, com `onkeypress` fica normal (mas tenho que usar `onkeyup`, porque serve também pra habilitar um botão se a data validar, e tem que ser ao acabar de digitar, e não ao perder o foco...).

```js
     function formatar(mascara, documento) {
                var i = documento.value.length;
                var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
                var texto = mascara.substring(i);
                if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
                    documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
                }
            }
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" onkeyup="formatar('##/##/####', this)" name="Tinsem3" id="Cinsem">
```

Tem jeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer com que a função não corra caso a tecla premida seja `backspace` ou `delete`. Nesse caso precisas de passar o evento à função e depois procurar se o código da tecla é 8 ou resp. 46.

```
onkeyup="formatar('##/##/####', this, event)"
```

e no JavaScript

```
function formatar(mascara, documento, e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.code;
    if (code == 8 || code == 46) return;
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9ejqaav/

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez Sérgio! Já és praticamente um sócio oculto do meu projeto! :-)  Apenas pra constar, incluí também os `keycodes` (nice tip, btw) das setas de voltar e avançar (arrow left e arrow rigth) porque vi agora que tbm estavam davam o mesmo problema, e a linha respectiva ficou assim: `if (code == 8 || code == 46 || code == 37 || code  == 39) return;`.